# How to uninstall my service on Windows XP with WiX

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

From what I understand about MSI installers, the removal of services during uninstallation is now done via [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But restart manager is not supported on Windows XP. So what is the official way to remove services in my MSI there?

PS. I'm coding the MSI markup using WiX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restart manager isn't needed to remove a service.  Just use the ServiceInstall and ServiceControl elements and as long your component is removed the service will be removed.

Restart Manager is more about hibernating a process and restoring it's state so that file locks are avoided and availability in maintained.